# `this` object cannot be read in channel bind pusher

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, pusher

```
channel.bind('Production_bid_91',function(response){
            console.log(response);


            dataSourceObj[0]['winner_user_name'] = response.winner_user_name;
            console.log(dataSourceObj[0]['winner_user_name']);


            this.state.dataSource = dataSourceObj;

        })
```

Code `this.state.dataSource = dataSourceObj;` is undefined...

How to make `channel` bind can read `this` object?

Comment: [How does the "this" keyword work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: Quick videos https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-catch-unsafe-use-of-this-in-typescript-functions / https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-make-usages-of-this-safe-in-class-methods 